# pyspark sql dataframe keep only null

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, null, pyspark

I have a sql dataframe `df` and there is a column `user_id`, how do I filter the dataframe and keep only `user_id` is actually null for further analysis? From the pyspark module page [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions), one can drop na rows easily but did not say how to do the opposite.

Tried `df.filter(df.user_id == 'null')`, but the result is 0 column. Maybe it is looking for a string "null". Also `df.filter(df.user_id == null)` won't work as it is looking for a variable named 'null'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
df.filter(df.user_id.isNull())
```